# Apply style to a <td> in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, dom, repeater

I need to apply style and highlight the header coloumn which is sorted..
Sorting is handled in rptMyTable_ItemCommand event.. i cant use gridview as the layout of displaying data is not a regular table.
in javascript we have something like
document.getElementById('lbCol1Header').parentNode.style = 'sortedColumnCSS'
how to do this in codebehind?

```
  <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="myCSS">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMyTable" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptMyTable_ItemCommand">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr style="font-weight: bolder">
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCol1Header" Text="Col1" runat="server" CommandName="sortCol1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCol2Header" Text="Col2" runat="server" CommandName="sortCol2" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCol3Header" Text="Col3" runat="server" CommandName="sortCol3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCol4Header" Text="Col4" runat="server" CommandName="sortCol4" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCol5Header" Text="Col5" runat="server" CommandName="sortCol5" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCol6Header" Text="Col6" runat="server" CommandName="sortCol6" />
                </td>                    
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
 //Table Data......with nested tables and divs
.
.
.
.
.
        </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
<tr style="font-weight: bolder">
    // doing paging operations here...
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try handling `ItemDataBound` event

Comment: thanks mshsayem, but how do i get reference to the html <td>.. it is not a server control..?

Comment: Cant think of something right now except: You can make those `td` server controls (`runat=server`) and give them some id; then you can get the reference of a column with `e.Item.FindControl("<id of the desired td>")`. Another hackish way can be: set some hidden field and make javascript to do the work (on docment load).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Design Page:

```
<tr class='<%# StyleSheet(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Y"))%>'>
```

for Linkbutton :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbCol1Header" Text="Col1" runat="server" CommandName="sortCol1" CssClass='<%# StyleSheet(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Y"))%>' />
```

In code Page:

```
 public static string StyleSheet(object objText1)
{
    string val = string.Empty;
    if (objText1.ToString() == "Y")
    {
        val = "trbind";
    }
    return val;
}
```

This is one of the way to apply style the in `tr` tag while in runtime based on the data.Similar you can try for the label also.

write the style `trbind` in stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .CssClass property in the rptMyTable_ItemCommand event I guess.

```
lbCol1Header.CssClass = "sortedColumnCSS";
```

If you want to apply the css class to  you should give ID and add runat="server".

```
<td ID="tdCol1Header" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCol1Header" Text="Col1" runat="server" CommandName="sortCol1" />
</td>
```

And to add the css class from your code behind.

```
tdCol1Header.Attributes("class") = "CssClass";
```

Comment: does it apply style to the table cell or the link button control?

Comment: To aplly the style to the table, you can give the table (or any HTML elements) an ID and run at server. Every control that has ID and run at server can be accessed from the code behind. See my updated answer. :)

Comment: thanks, is there any other approach other than applying runat=server for every header cell and applying styles? there are a lot of columns and was wondering if there is any other way?